# SetOnclick to a button created dynamically

Tags: android, button, pass-by-reference

I've got an activity with two tabs. **The first one** has a button. If you press this button, a tablerow is created with 3 views (ImageView, TextView, Button) **in the second tab**

I'd like to start a new activity when this button (the one we just created) is pressed but i don't know how i can make reference to it.

Note: There could be infinites tableRows.

Thanks!!

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
TextView view2 = new TextView(this);
Button view3 = new Button (this);

view.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
view.setPadding(1, 5, 0, 0);
view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

view2.setText("" + et.getText()  + dateFormat.format(c.getTime()) );
view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

view3.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
view3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

tr.addView(view, metrics.widthPixels/3, 150);
tr.addView(view2, metrics.widthPixels/2, 100);
tr.addView(view3, metrics.widthPixels/6, 20);
tl.addView(tr);
```

Comment: If you're creating all of the views in your row dynamically, just call the `setOnClickListener` method for your Button and pass in a listener that fires off the Intent.  You should post some code to better explain what exactly your issue is, as this question is quite vague and I suspect the answer isn't so simple...

Comment: I added my piece of code

Comment: Maybe should I add these buttons to a ButtonArray?

Comment: If my solution below works for you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the button, you have a reference to it; just add an OnClickListener to it like you would any other button:

```
Button view3 = new Button(this);
view3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick() {
     // do stuff
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you end up having a list of Button, then the easiest way is to use a for each loop to browse the collection, and call the setOnClickListener method on each of them (with the same instance of the listener, or not, depending on what you want):

```
// Instantiate the listener that will be used by the buttons.
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
     // do something...
   }
});

List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

// add button instances to the buttons list

for (Button button : buttons) {
    button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

Updated from author's comments:

Quick and dirty implementation where you instantiate one of those for each button, there is other many other solutions:

```
private class RowButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final String mActivityText;

    public RowButtonListener(Context context, String activityText) { // could be cleaner by providing resource id (int) if you use strings.xml
        mContext = context;
        mActivityText = activityText;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(MyActivity.TEXT_KEY, mActivityText);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, sorry.

Comment: Okay if I understand your code correctly, you want view3 to have a click listener. If that's the case, nothing is preventing you from calling setOnClickListener on that view3.

If you need to keep references on the buttons for your all your table rows for later usage, just add a field for your List<Button> and them to it.

Comment: Yeah, each time i press a button there's a new tablerow created. Each row has an image, a text and a button. So in the end there could be a lot of buttons. So you suggest that each time a button is created to add it to a listButton. But then, how can i know which button has been pressed? Because according to which button has been pressed i fill the activity with some stuff or other.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you do differently between different rows. What I can suggest is for you to figure out an algorithm to implement a class implementing the View.OnClickListener interface that could have a constructor where you can provide the various parameters that you describe.

So for each button, you could instantiate an instance of this class, providing the specific parameters.

Comment: The only difference is the text i'll display in the new acivity. It depends on the button pressed. I think i must read about this on the developers section because i'm a bit confused at the moment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Updated with a next example, hope it will help you.